# How to hide all the buttons once the user clicks on a few of them and give the user a new list of buttons to click in Racket

Tags: user-interface, button, racket

I'm trying to write a program where I want the user to click on some of the choices out of the 3 I give them and then after two of them get clicked I want the program to hide all the option choices and give them a new list of choices(buttons) that the user can click on. This is what I have for my code:

```
(define frame (new frame% [label "Choices in life"]
                   [width 460]
                   [height 460]))

(define canvas (new canvas% [parent frame]
                    [paint-callback
                     (lambda (canvas dc)
                       (send dc set-scale 3 3)
                       (send dc set-text-foreground red)
                       (send dc draw-text "The choice is yours" 19 30)
                       (send canvas set-canvas-background "black"))]))
```

Message that tells you to pick two of the three choices

```
(define search-company-msg (new message%
                                [label "Pick two of three:"]
                                [parent frame]
                                ))
```

a function that should hide the button (I want it to hide all buttons instantly after the user picks 2 out of the 3 choices. I know its not implemented right but this is just an idea I have:

```
(define hide-choice-1-2-3
  (lambda (button event)
    (send button style '(deleted))))

#choice 1

    (define choice-1
      (new button%
           [parent frame]
           [label "choice-1"]
           [min-width 200]
           [min-height 10]
           [callback (lambda (button event)
                (send button enable #f)
                       )]
           ))
#choice 2

(define choice-2
      (new button%
           [parent frame]
           [label "choice-1"]
           [min-width 200]
           [min-height 10]
           [callback (lambda (button event)
                (send button enable #f)
                       )]
           ))
#choice 3

(define choice-3
      (new button%
           [parent frame]
           [label "choice-1"]
           [min-width 200]
           [min-height 10]
           [callback (lambda (button event)
                (send button enable #f)
                       )]
           ))
```

these are the new choices I want to appear after two choices have been picked and the old choices disappear :

```
(define choice-4
          (new button%
               [parent frame]
               [label "choice-1"]
               [min-width 200]
               [min-height 10]
               [callback (lambda (button event)
                    (send button enable #f)
                           )]
               ))

(define choice-5
          (new button%
               [parent frame]
               [label "choice-1"]
               [min-width 200]
               [min-height 10]
               [callback (lambda (button event)
                    (send button enable #f)
                           )]
               ))
```

show the frame

```
(send frame show #t)
```

I know that `[style '(deleted)]`will hide the button but I don't know how to use that in terms of hiding all the buttons after only a few of them were picked. My other issue is making the new buttons appear in the frame by replacing the old buttons. I know there's a `add-child method` in the documentation but again I don't know how to use it. Can someone help me with code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not clear on what your overall aim is and I don't want to make a bunch of assumptions, but what you're looking for is the `delete-child` method of a class that implements the `area-container<%>` interface. The style `'deleted` is used to make a widget not visible or managed by the container on its creation; otherwise, you don't deal with it directly. In any case, simply adding new buttons will make them appear. For example:

```
#lang racket/gui
(define main-frame (new frame% (label "Main Frame")))

(define button-V
  (new vertical-panel% (parent main-frame)))

(define make-button
  (let ((used-index 0))
    (λ()
      (define b
        (new button%
             (parent button-V)
             (label (format "Button ~a" used-index))
             (callback (λ(b e)
                         (send button-V delete-child b)
                         (make-button)))))
        (set! used-index (add1 used-index))
        b)))

(for ((i (in-range 3)))
  (make-button))

(send main-frame show #t)
```

Depending on your aims you may need to manage children more explicitly than this. To do so, you would have the `'deleted` style to the buttons on their instantiation and then later determine which buttons to show via `add-child` or `change-children` , such as

```
(define B
    (new button%
         (parent button-V)
         (label "Mystery")
         (style '(deleted))))
; later... 
(send button-V add-child B)
```

***Edit:*** I have a complete example for you. I am sorry I took so long following up on my promise but I was unsure of finding an example that was reasonably short and reasonably clear. I don't know if I have achieved that goal.

The main strategy is 1) make a list of list of choices 2) index them 3) pass them to a procedure which generates buttons by consuming the first set of choices in the list 4) those buttons then can call the same procedure in (3) with the rest of the list of list of choices. As an added bonus I made the procedure able to loop and record the choices made.

I make no claims that this is a good way to do this, but it was a solution that occurred to me. The main problem with your question is that it *really* depends on what you want to do with the choices, as answering such a question will almost certainly have an impact on various data structure.

```
#lang racket/gui

(define main-frame
  (new frame% (label "Choose Your Fate")
       (width 250)))

(define button-panel
  (new vertical-panel% (parent main-frame)))

(define (clear-children)
  (send button-panel change-children (λ(x) '())))

; ((a b ...) ...) -> ((0 a b ...) (1 ...) ...)
(define (index-choices list-of-choices)
  (for/list ((choice list-of-choices)
             (index (in-naturals)))
    (cons index choice)))

(define choices
  (index-choices '((hello)
                   (yes no)
                   (one two three)
                   (left right up down))))

; all choices are done
; display the choices and offer a restart
(define (finish-choices)
  (clear-children)
  (new message% (parent button-panel)
       (label (responses->string responses)))
  (new button% (parent button-panel)
       (label "Restart")
       (callback (λ(b e)
                   (make-choice-buttons choices)))))


; ((index choices ...) rest...) -> index + (choices ...) (rest...)
(define (unpack choices)
  (let ((head (first choices)))
    (values (first head) (rest head) (rest choices))))

; #(symbols ...)
(define responses (build-vector (length choices) (λ(x) #f)))

; #(symbols ...) -> "symbols ..."
(define (responses->string res)
  (string-join
   (for/list ((val (in-vector res)))
     (symbol->string val))))

(define (make-callback index choice rest)
  (define (call button event)
    ;grab the response
    (vector-set! responses index choice)
    ; add next choices, or finish
    (if (empty? rest)
        (finish-choices)
        (make-choice-buttons rest)))
  call)
; ((index choices ...) rest...) -> buttons per choice
(define (make-choice-buttons choices)
  (define-values (this-index this-choice remaining-choices)
    (unpack choices))
  (clear-children)
  (for ((c this-choice))
    (new button%
         (parent button-panel)
         (label (symbol->string c))
         (callback (make-callback this-index c remaining-choices)))))

(make-choice-buttons choices)
(send main-frame show #t)
```

Comment: My overall aim is for the choices to change once I click on two of the original choices and then I want the new one to show. Can you show me how I would apply your technique on my code

Comment: @New_Racket_User I will try to think on this and edit my response in a bit.